# How to find the definition of Keras function?

Tags: keras

Keras' just provide a very brief definition of it's functions like:

```
Available metrics

binary_accuracy

binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)

...
```

But I want a math formula style definition, does anyone knows where can I find the math definitions of all the functions?

Answer (score 1):

Keras is open source project and you can find everything on github, for your questions, the metrics calculation code can be found here:

binary_accuracy
 = https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py#L20